# How to force xs layout in Bootstrap 3

Tags: mobile, layout, twitter-bootstrap-3, screen-resolution, screen-size

I'm making a small web project with Bootstrap 3.
At the top I've put this as it was suggested in most documents:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

It works fine on desktop but layout seems to be small on my smartphone (Galaxy Note). Because this web app will mostly be used on a smartphone I wanted to force small screen by adding this to head section of html:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=320">
```

It didn't work, I've got same layout as of screen resolution greater than 768px.

What I want to achieve is Bootstrap to act in xs layout in small-factor screen size, independent of screen resolution.

Thanks

UPDATE:
Here is the fiddle: [Fiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/rSrLL/)

> Display Metrics of my phone are: density=2.0 Dpi=320 heightPixels=800
>   scaledDensity=2.0 widthPixels=1280

EDIT:
Here are two screenshots. (I'll do a fiddle later) First is from phone, second from desktop. Desktop screenshot is what I want to get on a smartphone even if its resolution is on par with desktop. 
[image: Android Chrome on Galaxy Note screenshot]

Desktop:
[image: Desktop browser in small size]

UPDATE 2:
I've added this meta tag, but it didn't change anything on Android default browser or Chrome mobile:

```
<meta name="MobileOptimized" content="320">
```

Comment: What do you mean by small? Please create a fiddle and edit your question to include it. If you use the correct grid classes in your html, then, depending on what you want to do, your site is responsive so it's stacked on mobile devices and the columns are floated on larger widths.

Comment: Thanks for your interest in my question cab. I added a fiddle link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to achieve is overriding the basic premise of Bootstrap. Bootstrap uses the following scaling classes...

lg - For extra large displays
md - For standard sized displays such as desktops and laptops
sm - For tablet devices and devices with screens around the 7-11 inch range
xs - For mobile phones and devices with such small screens

The point of Bootstrap is to create a website style which will adjust itself based on the screen size automatically. You can use the md scaling class and if a smaller device is used then the elements will be collapsed and stacked on top of one another.

Comment: You are right, I've asked that question in my early days of Bootstrap, later 've figured my mistake/misunderstanding.